How to fix android.view.InflateException when using release apk
Who can help me.
This error only occurs when I use the release apk version, but the debug version does not:
Could not get package user id: run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.demo_with_nactive
2024-07-16 09:11:12.309 27244-27244 studio.deploy           pid-27244                            E  InstallClient: Could not copy '/data/local/tmp/.studio/tmp/69880af5/install_server' to '/data/data/com.example.demo_with_nactive/code_cache/install_server-69880af5: out='', err='run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.demo_with_nactive
run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.demo_with_nactive
'
2024-07-16 09:11:12.327 27244-27244 studio.deploy           pid-27244                            E  run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.demo_with_nactive
2024-07-16 09:11:12.408 27244-27244 studio.deploy           pid-27244                            E  Could not get package user id: run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.demo_with_nactive
2024-07-16 09:11:17.261  1680-1880  VerityUtils             pid-1680                             E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~ptwIyokEFQfvB1B2CZmE9A==/com.example.demo_with_nactive-bIeUDro8eMx50jPfyQAdbw==/base.apk
2024-07-16 09:11:17.381  1680-1880  VerityUtils             pid-1680                             E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~ptwIyokEFQfvB1B2CZmE9A==/com.example.demo_with_nactive-bIeUDro8eMx50jPfyQAdbw==/base.apk
2024-07-16 09:11:32.752 27411-27411 AndroidRuntime          pid-27411                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.demo_with_nactive, PID: 27411
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo_with_nactive/com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStreamActivityRebuild}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.example.demo_with_nactive:layout/activity_live_stream_rebuild: Binary XML file line #121 in com.example.demo_with_nactive:layout/activity_live_stream_rebuild: Error inflating class com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStream.Object.LiveStreamCameraLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3639)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3796)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2214)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.example.demo_with_nactive:layout/activity_live_stream_rebuild: Binary XML file line #121 in com.example.demo_with_nactive:layout/activity_live_stream_rebuild: Error inflating class com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStream.Object.LiveStreamCameraLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.example.demo_with_nactive:layout/activity_live_stream_rebuild: Error inflating class com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStream.Object.LiveStreamCameraLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at f.e.I(Unknown Source:23)
at androidx.appcompat.app.b.setContentView(Unknown Source:7)
at com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStreamActivityRebuild.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3612)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3796)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2214)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
2024-07-16 09:11:32.753 27411-27411 AndroidRuntime          pid-27411                            E      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/~~ptwIyokEFQfvB1B2CZmE9A==/com.example.demo_with_nactive-bIeUDro8eMx50jPfyQAdbw==/lib/arm64/librmmobilesdk.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1656)
at com.streamax.decode.NativeSurfaceView.(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:27060)
at com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStream.Object.LiveStreamCameraLayout.i(Unknown Source:35)
at com.example.demo_with_nactive.LiveStream.Object.LiveStreamCameraLayout.(Unknown Source:83)
... 31 more
I found the cause in this line of code but did not detect any unusual problems:
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_camera_playback, this);
